# Adding a custom password reset button in a custom sign in page - Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

So I have this sign in custom page

```
  <main>
  <section class="custom-acount-pages">
    <div class="custom-acount-pages__main">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Sign in to your account:</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
         <div id="api" data-name="Unified">
         </div>
        </div>
        <p>Forgot your password? <a href="#1" id="resetPasswordLink">Click here</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-acount-pages__side">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Don't have an account yet?</h2>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Get started now ></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>     
</main>
```

now what I want to do is when the user click on the `Forgot your password?` link, it redirects the user to the forgot password page/user flow. and when the user click on `Get started now>`, it redirects the user to the sign up page/user flow.

How to do this? How to add custom buttons and relate them to the pages manually? Thanks!!

Comment: You can check this custom policy for an example of an "embedded" password reset: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset.

Comment: @juunas Thank you but this link shows how to add the forget password that is added by azure itself. What I want to do is to be able to add it in other pages when it is not embedded. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Can you please confirm us What do you mean by add it in other pages..?